# GUI - hiding buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class dashboard(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(dashboard, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.buttons()

    def buttons(self):
        #student dashboard button
        bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Student",
                       command=self.student, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn1.grid()

        #teacher dashboard button
        bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Teacher", height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn2.grid()

        #exit button
        bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Exit",
               command=root.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn3.grid()

    def student(self):
        #view highscores button
        bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Highscores", height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn1.grid()

        #print score button
        bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Print Score", height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn2.grid()

        #exit button
        bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Main Menu",
               command=root.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn3.grid()



#main
root = Tk()
root.title("Dashboard")
root.geometry("300x170")
app = dashboard(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Wondered if someone could help me basically, with this GUI I am creating I want to be able to access a new page on the same frame but the buttons from the main menu stay once I go to another page, does anyone know how I can hide/forget the buttons and go back to them at a later stage? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a notebook control (http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html , https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Notebook) ?

Comment: Also, notebook example here: https://gist.github.com/mikofski/5851633

Comment: You could use `grid_forget` method.

Comment: `grid_forget()` hides widget. You could use `Frame` to group buttons and then you can hide one `Frame` and show another `Frame`.

Comment: BTW: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated to use sub-Frames**

You could do it using the universal `grid_remove()` method (here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-methods.html)). One way to use it would be to keep references to *each* of  the `Button` widgets created so you can call this method on them as needed.

However that can be simplified slightly—even though it takes about the same amount of code—by putting all the `Buttons`s for each page into a separate sub-`Frame` and just showing or hiding it which will automatically propagate do to all the widgets it contains. This approach also provides a better foundation for the rest of your program.

I've implemented this by adding a `main_button_frame` attribute to your class, as well as one named `student_button_frame` to hold those you have on the student page (since you'll probably need it to hide them too).

One nice thing about `grid_remove()` is that if you later call `grid()` on the same widget, it will remember all the settings it (and its sub-widgets) had before it was removed, so you don't need to create and maintain a list of every single one of them yourself.

Also note I also made some general modifications to your code so it conforms to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations better. I highly recommend you read and start following it.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Dashboard(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.main_button_frame = None
        self.student_button_frame = None
        self.create_main_buttons()

    def create_main_buttons(self):
        if self.student_button_frame:  # Exists?
            self.student_button_frame.grid_remove()  # Make it invisible.

        if self.main_button_frame:  # Exists?
            self.main_button_frame.grid()  # Just make it visible.
        else:  # Otherwise create it.
            button_frame = self.main_button_frame = Frame(self)
            button_frame.grid()

            # Student Dashboard button
            bttn1 = Button(button_frame, text="Student",
                           command=self.create_student_buttons, height=2,
                           width=15)
            bttn1.grid()

            # Teacher Dashboard button
            bttn2 = Button(button_frame, text="Teacher", height=2, width=15)
            bttn2.grid()

            # Dashboard Exit button
            bttn3 = Button(button_frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy,
                           height=2, width=15)
            bttn3.grid()

    def create_student_buttons(self):
        if self.main_button_frame:  # Exists?
            self.main_button_frame.grid_remove()  # Make it invisible.

        if self.student_button_frame:  # Exists?
            student_button_frame.grid()  # Just make it visible.
        else:  # Otherwise create it.
            button_frame = self.student_button_frame = Frame(self)
            button_frame.grid()

            # Highscores button
            bttn1 = Button(button_frame, text="Highscores", height=2, width=15)
            bttn1.grid()

            # Print Score button
            bttn2 = Button(button_frame, text="Print Score", height=2, width=15)
            bttn2.grid()

            # Student Exit button
            bttn3 = Button(button_frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy,
                           height=2, width=15)
            bttn3.grid()


# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Dashboard")
root.geometry("300x170")
app = Dashboard(root)
root.mainloop()
```